# Find angle using the sine and cosine formulas

Tags: trigonometry

Given that $\cos A = \frac{8}{17}$ find

a) $\sin 2A$

b) $\cos 2A$

Using $\cos A$ I can tell that $\sin A = \frac{15}{17}$

a) $\sin 2A = 2\sin A\cos A = \frac{240}{289}$

Is this correct?

b) $\cos 2A$

For this part, there are 3 formulas for expanding $\cos 2A$, is there any one I should favour over the others?

Say I chose $1 - 2\sin^2 A$, how could I find $A$?

Comment: I must also point out that in the line after b), you've written $2\cos A$ and not $\cos 2A$, which I presume is a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a)

No, it is not correct. If $\cos A=8/17$, then from $\cos^2A+\sin^2A=1$
$$\sin A=\color{red}{\pm}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{8}{17}\right)^2}=\color{red}{\pm}\frac{15}{17}$$
and so
$$\sin 2A=2\sin A\cos A=\color{red}{\pm}\frac{240}{289}$$

For b)

You can use whichever you like :
$$\cos 2A=2\cos^2A-1=1-2\sin^2A=\cos^2A-\sin^2A$$
By the way, note that $\cos^2A=(\cos A)^2$ and that $\sin^2A=(\sin A)^2$ : you don't need to find $A$.

Comment: @dagda1 Including the $\pm$ is important for the $\sin2A$ question as from the initial information you can not tell if $A$ is in the first or fourth quadrant. As such $\sin2A$ could have either sign. This is however not an issue for $\cos2A$ as $\frac{\pi}{4}\leq A\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{3\pi}{2}\leq A\leq\frac{7\pi}{4}$ and hence $2A$ will be in the second or third quadrant (respectively) and must be negative. (I'm leaving out adding on multiples of $2\pi$ as these don't change the calculations.)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\cos A = \frac{8}{17}$, you can use the identity $$\cos 2A = 2 cos^2 A -1 = 2\big( \frac{8}{17} \big)^2 -1 = -\frac{161}{289}$$.

It makes no difference which identity you choose to use for $\cos 2A$.  Try all three and prove it to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have that $\cos A = \frac{8}{17}$ and have deduced from this that $\sin A = \frac{15}{17}$. For part (a), as you have correctly stated, $$\sin 2A = 2\sin A \cos A = 2\left(\frac{15}{17}\times \frac{8}{17}\right) = \frac{240}{289}.$$

For part (b) you could use any one of the identites, I personally would use $$\cos2A = \cos^2A - \sin^2A,$$

but this is up to you. All that you must remember is that $$\cos^2A = \left( \cos A \right)^2,$$

and, of course, the same for the sine. Now you're all set.

Comment: is $\cos^2 A$ the same as $\cos A^2$?

Comment: No, $\cos^2 A = \left( \cos A \right)^2 = \left( \cos A \right)\left( \cos A \right)$.

Answer (score -1):

Draw a right angled triangle. This example uses Pythagorean triplets so integral sides occur.Only positive sign of $cos$ considered here. For negative sign change sign.

$$ c = 8/ 17 ;\ s  = 15/17 $$

$$ s_2 = 2 \cdot s \cdot c = =\frac {240}{289} = \pm 240/289 $$,

$$ c_2 =  c^2 -s^2 =  \frac {8^2-15^2}{289} = \pm \frac {-161}{289} .  $$